# Can't import subprocess module into python3

Tags: python, subprocess

Im trying to import subprocess. However Im unable to even import subprocess.

Currently, my file (throwaway.py) consists of only one line:

```
import subprocess
```

but it returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "throwaway.py", line 1, in <module>
    import subprocess
ImportError: bad magic number in 'subprocess': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time
ImportError: bad magic number in 'subprocess': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "throwaway.py", line 1, in <module>
    import subprocess
ImportError: bad magic number in 'subprocess': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
```

What are magic number errors? I read that they occur when you accidentally give a file the .pyc extention rather than .py?

Comment: Try and see if there are any subprocess.pyc files (use `locate`, if it's up to date). Check your local directory as well. Clear out/remove any `__pycache__` directories.

Comment: Thank you, there was a file named "test.pyc" perhaps it was created during one of my earlier attempts. removing it fixed the problem thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the error occurs because for some reason your code is importing **Python 2.7** `subprocess.pyc` into Python 3. Python 2.7 `.pyc`s start with `b'\x03\xf3\r\n'`. Perhaps you've created one virtualenv for both Python 2 and 3 (it **wouldn't work**), or are using a wrong `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pyclean` and try to import it again.

```
pyclean <path>
```

will remove all `pyc` files in path you'll provide (recursively), so there won't be compiled files, so no conflict.